# How to process a remote feed every second within Linux or PHP

Tags: php, cron, daemon, init

What is the sensible way to poll a remote feed each second from a Linux box?

I need to poll a remote feed over http every second, check for changes; then in response, modify some files that I'll be serving via Apache.

Cron on has a one minute resolution, so to use it, I could kick off a PHP script every minute then have the script run for a minute, polling the feed every second. There are problems with this as the PHP script could run for longer than a minute and then I'd either have two scripts running, or gaps of around a minute when no scripts are running.

The other idea I'm considering writing a daemon that will use curl to check the feed for differences and then fire up the PHP script to process those differences. I've never written a daemon before and I've no idea whether this would be overkill for my problem.

Comment: You want to gather information from a remote feed every second?  What happens if the previous poll hasn't finished? Every second is a lot, do you need it to be every second?

Comment: If the remote feed has the slightest lag, then connecting to the remote server, fetching the feed, checking for updates, potentially update files on your server might take longer than a second.

Comment: @Blinkydamo Unfortunately it does need to be about every second as we need to serve ''live' information. It takes less than 200ms to poll the feed and get the response and the processing I'm doing is light. Instead of polling every second on the second, I would be happy to poll 1 second after the last requests was complete.

Comment: Cron wont do it so have a look into using ajax with jquery's setInterval()

Comment: @Blinkydamo It can be done with cron, but the solutions I've seen seem hacky. Also, this is very much a server site problem, so I can't see anyway that ajax or jquery could be part of the solution.

Comment: NodeJS can handle this as you can pull down a stream of data and keep it running as a daemon-style process. If you are open to using NodeJS.